# What is a comprehensive integrated software stack for HR management, Learning Management, Financing and Procurement?

Tags: database, information-management, human-resources, jira, learning

I'm looking for a comprehensive solution for Human Recourses integrated with a learning and courses provider management solution along with the finance management related to procurements, department budgeting, salaries etc.

Basically I want two departments like HR and Training Center to able to share data between them with each having a user experience that's best suited for each department. From HR's perspective the employee is the most part that they are interested in. From the Training Center's perspective the courses and trainings that are being provided are the most important part.

Reporting and information about each employee from each department's respective view is the most crucial requirement for us. Also, being able to change and evolve with changing requirements is a plus.

For the hosting everything should on-premises.

I use Jira Software and Confluence personally and have seen plugins but I'm not sure how a full solution given our requirements will be implemented with Jira products.

Any help would be appreciated, I apologize in advance if the question is not clear enough, ask me and I will elaborate further. Thank You.